# How to create a shared spring configuration in a shared library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-configuration

I would like to create a shared library which provides default configuration to all my spring-boot web application clients. So far I was successfully able to create default actuator configuration using [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46492579). However, I'd like to provide the following three configurations:

```
spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=true
spring.cloud.config.discovery.service-id=MY-CLOUD-CONFIG-SERVER
spring.cloud.config.fail-fast=true
```

The clients are also successfully connecting to eureka and the config-server is up and running.

I have the following setup, that works for the actuator default config:

**com.livanov.test.DefaultActuatorConfiguration.java**

```
@PropertySource("classpath:default-actuator.properties")
public class DefaultActuatorConfiguration {

}
```

**META-INF/spring.factories**

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
  com.livanov.test.DefaultActuatorConfiguration
```

When I do the same class for the `spring.cloud.config.*` properties it doesn't work. I also tried to bind them in **spring.factories** with the `org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration` marker, but that doesn't work either. The clients in any of those setups are trying to connect to the default `8888` port of `cloud-config`. Probably I am missing what is the sequence of actions of the spring auto-configuration.

I also tried adding

```
@Order(Integer.MIN_VALUE)
```

and

```
@AutoConfigureBefore({
    ConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.class,
    DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.class
})
```

but those both look like hacks and actually don't work.