# How to share properties file among mutipule modules in microservice of spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

I'm using consul as my external config center, but it makes me annoying to copy lots of repeatable properties from a yaml to another, such as

```yaml
spring:
  data:
    redis:
      host: 192.168.124.133
      port: 6379
      password: root

  config:
    import: 'consul:'

  cloud:
    consul:
      host: 192.168.124.147
      port: 8500
      config:
        enabled: true
        prefixes: config
        default-context: application
        profile-separator: ','
        data-key: data
        format: yaml
      discovery:
        register: true
        prefer-ip-address: true
        instance-id: ${spring.application.name}-${server.port}
        service-name: ${spring.application.name}
        port: ${server.port}
        heartbeat:
          enabled: true
```

When I create another service-module, I have to copy this to another, even I don't need change anywhere.

Definately I have move some secret properties to config-center, but there are also properties to connect config-center and some necessary but not important properties

Now I have a parent-childrent project and create 2 modules `auth, common`

I have tried to declaring common as a dependency in auth, but it didn't work, the missing properties which have been moved to common caused the application start failure

Is there any solutation to resolve my problem?

---

addition:

My idea may like this:

```
parent
  |
  |--auth
  |   |
  |   |--resource/application.yaml.
  |
  |--common
      |
      |--resource/application.yaml
```

auth and common are modules of parent, now I can edit common's application.yaml

```yaml
# config in commons

spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      host: 192.168.124.147
      port: 8500
      config: ...

com:
  example:
    my:
      auth:
        parameter: Authorization
        time: 1
        unit: hours
        config: ...
    
......
```

cause `common declares` dependency of [spring.cloud.consul] and [com.example.my.auth], then `auth import common` and can `extends its yaml config properties`, and it also can replace any propertiy easily

```
# config in auth
spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      host: 192.168.124.148
      # no need to change other default props defined in common

com:
  example:
    my:
      auth:
        time: 2
        # no need to change other default props defined in common
```

Comment: modules should be independent from each other (properties-wise), and normally properties are duplicated as needed. However since the modules are probably sharing Spring Context, I am thinking you could create a ConfigurationProperties bean and get properties from that bean that you autowire wherever needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the answer.

I have searched a lot and finally I got the reason.

Defaultly, if there are two modules `auth` and `common`, both of them have the same name properties file `resource\application.yaml`, in this case, if `auth depends on common`, then the properties file of common `will be coverd and ignored` cause one module will only have a applcation.yaml valid in `resource`, definately auth's priority is bigger than commom's

However, Spring supports another way to allow us do that. According to [2.3. External Application Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files), Spring boot will load properties files from different location and has different priority. To avoid the shared props file be covered by current project, we can put it at `resource\config\application.yaml`, then it will works well.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, since the common module is included in all those sub-modules, that you should be able to place the property file there, and then use `@PropertySource("classpath:<file_name>")` on top of a `@Configuration` class in each sub-module.

OR, you could create the configuration in the shared module itself, and then export it as an auto-configuration.

So, sth like:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("default-application.properties")
public class SharedConfiguration {

}
```

and then, inside `META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports`:

```
my.package.SharedConfiguration
```

Comment: Actuall it do jump to the `application-comon.yaml` when i use @PropertySource("classpath:application-common.yaml"). But I still got `No spring.config.import property has been defined` cause I move it to common, may be I can't read lib properties from other module?

Comment: It might be because of the filename. By convention, `application-common` will only be applied if a profile named `common` is active

Comment: I change the name `application-common.yaml to application.yaml`, but it still doesn't work. I set `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.example.my.auth", "com.example.my.commons"})` and set `@PropertySource("classpath:application.yaml")` on a empty Configuration class, and I got this error again. I do can get 2 candidate application.yaml when i clik the `classpath:application.yaml` at PropertySource

Comment: Just double-checking: the properties were previously defined inside `application.yaml`, right? NOT `bootstrap.yaml`? BC if you're asking how to externalize `bootstrap.yaml`, that's a different issue altogether, and you should look for the answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888231/how-to-manage-spring-cloud-bootstrap-properties-in-a-shared-library) instead

Comment: Asking bc `spring.cloud.consul.config.enabled=true` would normally be expected in `bootstrap.yml`, not `application.yml`

Comment: Sadly it looks work well at first, but then i got `Parameter 1 of method configWatch in ... required a single bean, but 2 were found:` since  moving those properties to bootstrap.yaml. After talking with Bing AI, I supposed that bootstrap may do have conflict with springcloud-config for reason duplicate registration